# Swift: Declaring pointer to point to a field of struct

Tags: ios, pointers, audio, swift

I am trying to write audio apps in Swift, but encountered a problem to declare a pointer to access `mBuffers` in `AudioBufferList` correctly.

In Swift, `AudioBufferList` is declared as follows:

```
struct AudioBufferList {
    var mNumberBuffers: UInt32
    var mBuffers: (AudioBuffer)
}
```

which `mBuffers` is declared as a single AudioBuffer but in fact it should be a variable length array of `AudioBuffer` (whose length are given by `mNumberBuffers`).

So I tried to declare a pointer to point to `mBuffer`:

```
var buffers:UnsafePointer<AudioBuffer> = &bufferList?.mBuffers
```

However, This will result in a weird compile error:

> error: cannot convert the expression's type 'inout $T4' to type 'inout $T4'
>           var buffers:UnsafePointer = &bufferList?.mBuffers
>                                                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

How should I declare a AudioBuffer pointer to point to `mBuffers` correctly? Thanks.

Comment: Wouldn't you rather have an `Array<AudioBuffer>`? Why the pointers? Pointers are useful when you want to well... point to an arbitrary location in memory you know more than the compiler about. In your case you _know_ the structure - an array of AudioBuffer.

Comment: The AudioBufferList should still be a C structured array instead of a swift Array?